# Angular div remove animation

Tags: angular

I put an animation on my div

```
<div [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{delay: '200ms',scale:'0.2'}}"> content </div>
```

Now, what I want is that that animation will happen only once upon page loading. Then I don't want to happen again. How can I dynamically remove it?

Comment: Could you include at least the animation definition? I think you want to look at the `:enter` state transition and use an `ngIf` to trigger the initial transition from void to something.

Comment: You could use the `[hidden]` directive.